# Last Day Function - Data Set Oracle Fusion

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, middleware, fusion

Im using Oracle Fusion in my enterprise project. We have to create a report that must include last day of a certain date in this format 'May-16' for example.

This date field is result of a SQL query and is stored in the data set and I want to get the last day of that field using a global function.

[image]

How can I do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't tell for sure if this is the question you are asking, but...

assuming you want to know how to select the last day in a column in a table using straight SQL (where "last" is with regard to ordering BY THAT COLUMN), then it should be as simple as

```
select max(date_field) as effective_end_date
from   your_table;
```

If you need to filter your records (rows) first, by applying some conditions like product_id = 100 (made-up example!) you can add those filtering conditions in a `where` clause.

Comment: Well, that's not the way I was looking for... but it has the same result. Thanks you so much!!